# Horizontal Lines on top of each bar in bar chart - ChartJs 4.4

Tags: asp.net-core, chart.js, razor-pages

i want to plot a targetline for each bar in a barchart as shown below,

[image]

i am using Chart Js 4.4. Here is my code where i have implemented the barchart.
i tried to add another dataset, but its not mapping correctly.And also the x-axis labels are showing twice.

```
var WeeklyData = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.UDTSLDDailyPVA.ToList()))
            console.log(WeeklyData);


        let weeklylabels = [...new Set(WeeklyData.map((x) => x.Day))];
        console.log(weeklylabels);

        let weeklydatasets = (WeeklyData.map((y) => y.TotalActual));
        console.log(weeklydatasets);

        //let weektarget = (WeeklyData.map((y) => y.WeekTarget));
        //console.log(weektarget);

        

        var barChartDataWeekly = {
            labels: weeklylabels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: weeklydatasets,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 154, 221, 1)'  
                }
            ],
        };

window.onload = function () {
            var ctxUPHHistory = document.getElementById('barChartUPHHistory').getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctxUPHHistory, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartDataWeekly,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    parsing: {
                        xAxisKey: 'Day',
                        yAxisKey: 'TotalActual'
                    },                        
                    scales: {                            
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        };
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your image is blur. Can you change the picture to higher resolution, provide the draft (drawing) of your expected result with the sample data? Thanks.

Comment: @Yong Shun , I have changed my image. Please check.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are trying to plot the horizontal line with `WeekTarget`.

First, you need to include the [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/) library.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
```

Next, you need to build the `annotations` object to plot the line in the correct y-axis value, the x-axis length, styling and etc.

```js
let weektarget = WeeklyData.map((y) => y.WeekTarget);

var annotations = weektarget.reduce(function (acc, cur, i) {
    acc[`line${i}`] = {
      type: 'line',
      yMin: cur,
      yMax: cur,
      xMin: -0.25 + i,
      xMax: 0.25 + i,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 2,
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Lastly, add the `annotations` object in `options.plugins.annotation.annotations`.

```js
new Chart(ctxUPHHistory, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartDataWeekly,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'Day',
        yAxisKey: 'TotalActual',
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        annotation: {
          annotations: annotations
        }
      },
    },
  });
```

[JS Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vcdmdn?file=index.html)

> Result

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Its working as expected. Thank You so  much for your help!

Comment: Hi, I have one requirement: If i dont want to plot the horizontal value for certain  x values, how can i give the condition ?Kindly let me know if i need to raise as a new request.

Comment: Hi, ya, would be great if you create another question and specify the requirement as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Hi i have posted the question .Please find the link below .Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400209/showing-annotation-line-based-on-condition